# How to collect terms with positive powers in polynomial

Tags: pattern-matching, polynomials

I am trying to collect all terms with non-negative powers of $x$ in polynomials like
$\frac{1}{x^2}\left(a x^2+x^{\pi }+x+z\right)^2$

First expand the polynomial

```
Expand[1/x^2 (x + x^π + a x^2 + z)^2, x]
```

This gives  $a^2 x^2+2 a x^{\pi }+2 a x+2 a z+2 x^{\pi -2} z+x^{2 \pi -2}+2 x^{\pi -1}+\frac{z^2}{x^2}+\frac{2 z}{x}+1$.

Now try to select those terms with positive or zero powers of x. My best guess is

```
Plus@@Cases[%, (Times[___, Power[x, g_.], ___] /; g >= 0)]
```

However, this only yields the term $a^2 x^2$.

And why does this not work for the other terms?
How can I collect the other terms with positive or zero powers of x?

Comment: FWIW, these expressions are not what is usually meant by "polynomial."  By definition, a polynomial has only *natural numbers* ($0,1,2,\ldots$) among the powers of its variables.  Neither are these rational expressions, which are polynomial fractions.  The conventional term that comes closest to what may be intended here is "[posynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posynomial)."

Comment: @whuber actually they are called _Laurent polynomials_

Comment: @Spawn1701D I don't think so: such objects would not include fractional or irrational powers, for instance.

Comment: @whuber have a look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaurentPolynomial.html) for more details.

Comment: @Spawn1701D Read carefully: irrational and fractional powers won't even make sense in most fields $\mathbb{F}$.  BTW, Mathworld tends not to be the best choice of references, as attested by its sloppy (and incorrect) definition of [polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polynomial.html): although from the article it is clear that only non-negative integers can be possible powers (as in its equation 2), nowhere does it actually state that!

Comment: @whuber yes you are totally correct, sorry I was stuck in the positive power statement and oblivious to your Real statement ...

Comment: I notice that you never Accepted an answer to this question.  Does anything remain unaddressed or unsatisfactory?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Everything clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use `Pick` and `Exponent`:

```
list = List @@ Expand[1/x^2 (x + x^Pi + a x^2 + z)^2, x];
Pick[list, Positive[Exponent[#, x] & /@ list]]

(*{2 a x,a^2 x^2,2 x^(-1+Pi),2 a x^Pi,x^(-2+2 Pi),2 x^(-2+Pi) z}*)
```

Or a little shorter, since `Exponent` has attribute `Listable` (thanks to [Mr. Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) for pointing that out):

```
Pick[list, Positive@Exponent[list, x]]
```

Comment: +1 This seems like the correct approach.  Also, I believe you can write: `Pick[list, Positive @ Exponent[list, x]]`

Comment: One-liner: `Select[Expand[1/x^2 (x + x^\[Pi] + a x^2 + z)^2], Positive[Exponent[#, x]] &]`

Comment: @J.M. Very nice!  Perhaps not as fast a `Pick` however?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I suppose timings might be in order... :)

Comment: @einbandi Also in your answer I am missing $1$ and $2az$. You can include them by changing Positive[] into NonNegative[]

Answer (score 6):

Your pattern is evaluating in an undesired way; you can use `HoldPattern` to avoid this:

```
expr = Expand[1/x^2 (x + x^π + a x^2 + z)^2, x];

Plus @@ Cases[expr, (HoldPattern[Times[___, Power[x, g_.], ___]] /; g >= 0)]
```

> ```
> 2 a x + a^2 x^2 + 2 x^(-1 + π) + 2 a x^π + 2 x^(-2 + π) z
> ```

Because of the attributes of `Times` you do not need two `___` patterns, which was the source of the problem above (they evaluated to `___^2`).  *EDIT:* Also, the pattern above misses the term `x^(2π - 2)`.  We can instead write:

```
Tr @ Cases[expr, x^g_. _. /; g >= 0]
```

> ```
> 2 a x + a^2 x^2 + 2 x^(-1 + π) + 2 a x^π + x^(-2 + 2 π) + 2 x^(-2 + π) z
> ```

---

In a comment sjdh states that he expects `1` and `2 a z` terms to be present in the output.
Perhaps this is closer to his intent:

```
DeleteCases[expr, x^g_. _. /; g < 0]
```

> ```
> 1 + 2 a x + a^2 x^2 + 2 x^(-1 + π) + 2 a x^π + x^(-2 + 2 π) + 2 a z + 2 x^(-2 + π) z
> ```

Comment: @Mr.Wizzard $1$ and $2az$ also have a non negative power of $x$. Why are they not included in your answer? I thought MatchQ[1, x^_.] would give True, but it yields False.

Comment: @sjdh I updated my answer; please tell me if this gives the output you desire.

Comment: @sjdh Also, the default value for `Power` is one, not zero, which I believe explains your non-match above.

Comment: @Mr.Wizzard Using DeleteCases is a good idea. This works. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
Expand[1/x^2 (x + x^π + a x^2 + z)^2, x] /. x^_?Negative -> 0
```

> $1+2 a x+a^2 x^2+2 x^{-1+\pi }+2 a x^{\pi }+x^{-2+2 \pi }+2 a z+2 x^{-2+\pi } z$

Answer (score 3):

```
p = {Expand[1/x^2 (x + x^Pi + a x^2 + z)^2]};
Extract[p, Position[N@p, x^n_ /; n > 0, Infinity][[All, 1 ;; 2]]]

(* {a^2 x^2, 2 x^(-1 + Pi), 2 a x^Pi, x^(-2 + 2 Pi), 2 x^(-2 + Pi) z}*)
```

Comment: Can you add some comments? How is it working? What is the difference with the other answers?

Comment: @sjdh I don't know how _it's different_. I wrote this answer before any other was posted, and I think it's correct. There are only a few seconds elapsed between my post and Mr.Wizard's