# How can a power of 0 or 1 be replaced?

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

Consider this given example for [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html)

```
1 + x^2 + x^4 /. x^p_ -> f[p]
```

This returns `1+f[2]+f[4]` - works good (!). But if you choose

```
 In[175]:= 1 +x+ x^2 + x^4 /. x^p_ -> f[p]
 Out[175]= 1+x+f[2]+f[4]
```

It doesn't not work for `1` and `x`. The correct output should be `f[0]+f[1]+f[2]+f[4]`.

What is wrong here and to cure it?

**EDIT**

> Possible way out

One possible way out can be to not use `ReplaceAll` (inspired by @eldo). The coefficient and the power of `x`  can be combined in this way:

```
fun[x] = a - b x + c x^2 + d x^4
nfun = Exponent[fun[x], x];
Sum[Coefficient[fun[x], x, i] f[i], {i, 0, nfun}]
```

And the result is `a f[0] - b f[1] + c f[2] + d f[4]`.

However the replace rule for $x^0$ is still a mystery!

Comment: 1 does not match x^0 but To obtain f[1], write `1 + x + x^2 + x^4 /. x^p_. :> f[p]`  notice the `p_.` pattern. This now returns `1 + f[1] + f[2] + f[4]` see http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Patterns.html

Comment: Thanks @Nasser (specially for the information about patterns). But I would be still interested to know if there is any way to do it with `Replace` for 1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I replace a variable in a polynomial?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/552/how-do-i-replace-a-variable-in-a-polynomial)

Comment: I don't think so @Artes. The problem is not with the replacement in general but with power 0 and 1. Even if you consider your own answer in the referrence `z^4 + z^2 + 4 /. z^(a_Integer) -> x^(1/2 a)` and use `1 + z + z^2 /. z^(a_Integer) -> f[a]`, you can see it doesn't work for 1 and z, and that is exactly where my question is.

Comment: thanks @bobthechemist. This is fine. The earlier title was probably a bit misleading for quick glance.

Comment: @Sumit I think you found an excellent solution :)

Comment: @Daniel Seems to work in all cases considered so far. Please transform your comment into an answer.

Comment: Related: [(23066)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23066).  Also this answer of mine may be helpful in guiding the application of patterns: [(30907)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30919).  Finally, this may serve as a useful warning against making a pattern too general: [(17497)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17497)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be cumbersome with `ReplaceAll`. I suggest to use `Exponent` instead:

```
Plus @@ (f /@ Exponent[1 + x + x^2 + x^4, x, List])
```

> f[0] + f[1] + f[2] + f[4]

**Considering Öska's objection**

Alternating signs are not easily handled, maybe something like this:

```
fun1 = 1 - x - x^2 + x^4;
fun2 = List @@ fun1;

minus = Position[fun2, Times[-1, __]] // Flatten;
plus = Complement[Range@Length@fun2, minus];

fun3 = (f /@ Exponent[fun1, x, List]);

Plus @@ Join[Part[fun3, plus], Part[fun3, minus] /. a_ :> -a]
```

> f[0] - f[1] - f[2] + f[4]

**ADDENDUM**

This can be shortened to:

```
 Plus @@ (D[#, x] & /@ MonomialList@fun1 /. Times[a_?NumberQ, __] :> a /. 
    a_?NumberQ :> f[Abs@a]*Sign@a /. (0) -> f@0*First@fun1)
```

> f[0] - f[1] - f[2] + f[4]

Comment: What if one has `1 + x - x^2 + x^4`? Using `Plus` is a wrong IMO.

Comment: Can it be generalised for a series like `Sum[a[n]x^n,{n,0,3}]`? One hard way would be to find the individual `Coefficient` and then combine with `Exponent`. I wonder if there is any less complex way!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a set of replacements that works on the following test cases:

```
test1 = 1 + x + x^2 + x^4;
test2 = 2 + x - x^2 + x^4;
test3 = -2 - x + x^2 - x^4;
test4 = -2 - x - x^2 - x^4;
rules = {
   (* For x^0 *)
   n_?NumberQ :> If[n > 0, 1, -1] f[0],
   (* For  positive x^1 *)
   n_ /; Head[n] == Symbol :> f[1],
   (* for positive x^n *)
   n_^p_ :> f[p],
   (* For negative x^1 or x^n *)
   n_ /; Head[n] == Times :> (
     Replace[n, {m_ /; Head[m] == Symbol :> f[1], m_^p_ :> f[p]}, 1]
     )
   };

Replace[#, rules, 1] & /@ {test1, test2, test3, test4} // Column

(* {f[0] + f[1] + f[2] + f[4],
f[0] + f[1] - f[2] + f[4], 
-f[0] - f[1] + f[2] - f[4], 
-f[0] - f[1] - f[2] - f[4]} *)
```

The rules are desgined based on the observation that Head[n_] will be Times if there is a negative sign in front of x.

```
Head /@ # & /@ {test1, test2, test3, test4}
(* 
{Integer + 2 Power + Symbol, 
Integer + Power + Symbol + Times,
Integer + Power + 2 Times, 
Integer + 3 Times} 
*)
```

Therefore, I want to develop one rule for the *^0 case and two rules for the x^* cases.  The way I've done this is to take a nested replacement approach so that I can call the replacement only once if the coefficient is positive and twice if the coefficient is negative.  I don't think I can figure out a solution using ReplaceAll.

Comment: What about `2 + x - x^2 + x^4` ?. Gives me `2 + f[1] - f[2] + f[4]`

Comment: @eldo right, thinking....

Comment: I think you could append `/. f[0] -> f[0]*First@test1` to `test1 /. rules` to account for the negative case.

Comment: @eldo I tried a different (clunkier?) approach that seems to work.

Answer (score 6):

If only one (or perhaps two) variables are involved, and the expression is polynomial therein and of modest degree, then it's straightforward to do this with `CoefficientList` and `Dot` as in the example below.

```
With[{cc = CoefficientList[1 + x^2 + x^4, x]}, 
 cc.Thread[f[Range[0, Length[cc] - 1]]]]

(* Out[357]= f[0] + f[2] + f[4] *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully I don't misunderstand, but I think this does what you request:

```
1 + x + x^2 + x^4 /. {x^p_. :> f[p], 1 :> f[0]}
```

> ```
> f[0] + f[1] + f[2] + f[4]
> ```

The use of [`Optional`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Optional.html) handles the case of `x`, but since `x` is not present in `1` we need an additional rule for that.  Please also note the use of [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RuleDelayed.html) to correctly localize `p`.

If you allow modification of the function `f` itself we could establish:

```
f[] = f[0];
```

Then:

```
1 + x + x^2 + x^4 /. x^p_. | 1 :> f[p]
```

> ```
> f[0] + f[1] + f[2] + f[4]
> ```

This works via [*vanishing patterns*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44084/121).

Comment: the simplicity of the '.'...and delay

Answer (score 4):

Just for variety:

```
fun[poly_] := Total[f[First@#1] #2 & @@@ CoefficientRules[poly]]
```

Some test cases:

```
test = {1 + x + x^2 + x^4, 1 - x - x^2, 1 + 2 x + 3 x^3}
```

yields:

```
Grid[{#, fun@#} & /@ test, Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left]
```

[image]

I just note this answer is consistent with others, e.g Daniel Lichtblau. However, OP wanted 1+x^2+x^4->1+f[2]+f[4]...

Comment: In my humble opinion one of the best answer so far. The OP wanted exactly this. Don't understand your "However..."

Answer (score 3):

A rule for $x^0$ will never be applied if `x^_` is not there in the original equation.

(*Note:* You can do this for $x^1$: `4 - 3 x + 2 x^2 - x^5 /. {x^p_ :> f@p, Power@x -> f@1}`, cf. `OneIdentity` attribute that is assigned to `Power`.)

`CoefficientList` will probably be the best choice for you:

```
In[1]:= With[{c = CoefficientList[#, x]}
        , c.(f /@ (Range@Length@c - 1)) ]&[4 - 3 x + 2 x^2 - x^5]
Out[1]= 4 f[0] - 3 f[1] + 2 f[2] - f[5]
```

However, you can always define your own structures. For example, you could introduce `power` that never evaluates. To make it printed the way the original is printed, you can do the following:

```
In[2]:= MakeBoxes[power[x_, p_], tag_] ^:= 
        With[{boxes = MakeBoxes[Power[x, p], tag]}
        , InterpretationBox[boxes, power[x, p]]]
```

Now you can have a transformer for polynomials [of one variable]

```
In[3]:= toLazyPowers[poly_, x_] /; PolynomialQ[poly, x] :=
        With[{c = CoefficientList[poly, x]}
        , c.(power[x, #] & /@ (Range@Length@c - 1))]
```

that returns expressions with explicit “powers”, only those powers don't have any definitions associated with them:

```
In[4]:= toLazyPowers[4 - 3 x + 2 x^2 - x^5, x]
Out[4]= 4 x^0 - 3 x^1 + 2 x^2 - x^5
```

Then you will be able to perform replacements with $x^0$:

```
In[5]:= toLazyPowers[4 x^0 - 3 x^1 + 2 x^2 - x^5, x] /. power[x, p_] :> f@p
Out[5]= 4 f[0] - 3 f[1] + 2 f[2] - f[5]
```

To go back, replace your `power` with original `Power`:

```
In[6]:= Out@4 /. power -> Power
Out[6]= 4 - 3 x + 2 x^2 - x^5
```

which can be formalised, e.g., this way:

```
In[7]:= toEagerPowers@expr_ := expr /. power -> Power
```

*Note:* Sure, you can enrich `power` with definitions like

```
power[power[expr_, n_Integer], m_Integer] := power[expr, n m]
```

but prior to doing that, it's better to ask yourself what exactly you need this symbol for. In the example above it's actually used for printing polynomials, and not much for anything else. For “regular representations” of polynomials in terms of Mathematica's data structures you don't need powers at all; coefficients lists, maybe combined with a custom head, would do.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to multiply by a symbolic term $x^n$ so that every term matches the pattern, and subtract $n$ from the matched power:

```
expr = 10/x + 2 + x + x^2 + x^4

Module[{n},
 Expand[expr x^n] /. x^p_. :> f[p - n]
 ]

(* 10 f[-1] + 2 f[0] + f[1] + f[2] + f[4] *)
```

Comment: neat use of symbolic manipulation...think i could use this

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a pretty simple solution that should cover the most important cases.

The trick is to convert all numbers `n` (including all coefficients) to `n f[0]`, then use a pattern that converts expressions such `n f[0] f[3]` to `n f[3]`.

```
f /: Times[rest___, f[0], f[x_]] := Times[rest, f[x]]
convert[sym_Symbol] := {sym :> f[1], sym^n_ :> f[n], n_?NumericQ :> n f[0]}
```

A test:

```
3*(-5) x + I x^2 - a x^3 + 6 /. convert[x]
```

> `6 f[0] - 15 f[1] + I f[2] - a f[3]`

---

You can extend `convert` to work with symbolic additive constants like this:

```
conv[sym_Symbol, c___] := {
  sym :> f[1],
  sym^n_ :> f[n],
  n_?NumericQ :> n f[0],
  Sequence @@ (# :> # f[0] & /@ {c})}
```

You will have to supply the constants to be covered as additional arguments. An example:

```
a + b + c + a x^2 + b x^2 /. conv2[x, a, b, c]
```

> `a f[0] + b f[0] + c f[0] + a f[2] + b f[2]`

If you want to collect the `f`-Terms, just use `FullSimplify`:

```
a + b + c + a x^2 + b x^2 /. conv2[x, a, b, c] // FullSimplify
```

> `(a + b + c) f[0] + (a + b) f[2]`

Answer (score 1):

For Version 9.0.1.0 (Windows 8 64-bit), this seems to be a good use case for the function `` Internal`FromCoefficientList ``:

```
bifclF = Block[{Power = f[#2] &, x = f[1]}, Internal`FromCoefficientList[#, x]] &
```

Examples: Using @bobthechemist's examples

```
test1 = 1 + x + x^2 + x^4; test2 = 2 + x - x^2 + x^4;
test3 = -2 - x + x^2 - x^4; test4 = -2 - x - x^2 - x^4;

cls = CoefficientList[#, x] & /@ {test1, test2, test3, test4}
```

> {{1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {2, 1, -1, 0, 1}, {-2, -1, 1, 0, -1}, {-2, -1, -1,  0, -1}}

```
bifclF /@ cls
```

> {f[0] + f[1] + f[2] + f[4],
>        2 f[0] + f[1] - f[2] + f[4],
>        -2 f[0] - f[1] + f[2] - f[4],
>        -2 f[0] - f[1] - f[2] - f[4]}

In version 10, this approach misses `f[0]`s.

Comment: It seems to me that undocumented functionality can be avoided by using `FromDigits`: `Block[{Power = f[#2] &, x = f[1]}, FromDigits[Reverse@{-2, -1, 1, 0, -1}, x]]` -- or am I mistaken?

Comment: Mr.Wizard, it gives `-2 - f[1] + f[2] - f[4]` (that is, it misses   `f[0]`)

Comment: I missed that because in 10.0 your `bifclF /@ cls` outputs `{1 + f[1] + f[2] + f[4], 
 2 + f[1] - f[2] + f[4], -2 - f[1] + f[2] - f[4], -2 - f[1] - f[2] - f[4]}`.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Wizard, I hadn't tried it in version 10. I'll add the "Version 9 only"  caveat. Another reminder not to rely on undocumented functions.