# Account for powers of 0 and 1 when defining function

Tags: function-construction

I have a function that I am defining as (assume m,n,a,b are non-negative integers):

```
myfcn[x_^m_ p_^n_, x_^a_ p_^b_] := basefcn[m, n, a, b];
```

and then extending to all polynomials by linearity.

The way I defined the function above works as long as m,n,a,b are all greater than 1, but fails otherwise. For instance, I want `myfcn[x p^2, p]` to evaluate to `basefcn[1,2,0,1]`, but mathematica does not recognize that this is what I want.

How do I extend my function definition to include these cases without explicitly writing out all possible input forms?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some silliness with [`Optional`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html) i.e. `:` (thanks @Mr.Wizard for the `-.` tip). <strike>I thought I could ride the `Optional` gravy train all the way but just could not find a way to deal with arguments that equal to `1` i.e. `x^0 p^0`, so I defined another instance of the function to convert `1` to `x^0 p^0` (and then pass it back to the original definition)</strike> (oh yes I can!). This also does seem to be monomial-only.

A small note: since `x` and `p` have to be specified (otherwise `x` could just as well stand for `p_`), I left the base as `x` and `p`, instead of `x_` and `p_`; they are not used by the function anyway so it really doesn't matter much.

```
ClearAll[myfcn, x, p]
SetAttributes[myfcn, HoldAll]

myfcn[(c1 : 1 : 1) (x1 : x^m_. : x^0) (p1 : p^n_. : p^0),
  (c2 : 1 : 1) (x2 : x^a_. : x^0) (p2 : p^b_. : p^0)] :=
 basefcn[m, n, a, b]

myfcn[x p^2, p]
(* basefcn[1, 2, 0, 1] *)

myfcn[x p^2 + p, p]
(* myfcn[x p^2 + p, p] *)

{Defer[myfcn][Sequence @@ #], myfcn @@ #} & /@ 
  Partition[Flatten[Outer[x^#1 p^#2 &, {0, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 2}]]~Prepend~1, 2] // 
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I was about to post an answer using `Optional`.  You win this time.  However, you do not need to use e.g. `(m_: 1)` as `m_.` will do since `1` is the default value for `Power`.  This significantly streamlines your code.  See: [(51585)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51585)

Comment: Also I note that you are using literal `x` and `p` in your function whereas by my interpretation of the question these are arbitrary symbols or expressions.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks so much for the `_.` tip! Could I edit my post to add that in? Also, the reason I chose to use explicit `x` and `p` is because the function the OP defines (with `x_` and `p_`) is ambiguous. For example, using OP's definition, `myfunc[x^2, p^3]` could be matched such that `x^2` matches `x_^m_`, and `p^3` matches `p_^b_`. However, `x^2` could just as well match with `p_^n_`, and `p^3` with `x_^a_`, since `x_` and `p_` in OP's definition could be anything. Please let me know if I might be confused on that point.

Comment: I also apologize if my answer had made you abandon your answer. I don't doubt your method with `Optional` would be better/more elegant than mine.

Comment: Your method looks fine.  I was taking a different approach but I don't think it would be useful to the OP as there were unresolved issues, which your choice of literal `x` and `p` better addressed.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps

```
myfcn2[arg1_, arg2_] := basefcn @@ Flatten[Exponent[#, {x, p}, List] & /@ {arg1, arg2}]; 
myfcn2[x p^2, p]
(* basefcn[1, 2, 0, 1] *)
```

**Update:** To restrict the arguments to monomials (Thanks: @wxffles )

```
ClearAll[myfnc3];
myfcn3[arg1_, arg2_] /; FreeQ[{arg1, arg2}, Plus] := 
      basefcn @@ Flatten[Exponent[#, {x, p}, List] & /@ {arg1, arg2}];
myfcn3[x p^2 , p]
(* basefcn[1, 2, 0, 1] *)
myfcn3[x p^2 + p , p]
(* myfcn3[p + p^2 x, p] *)
```

Comment: Is there a way I can make it only use the implementation you give when arg1 and arg2 are monomials? Because if they are polynomials (i.e. arg1 = x p + x^2 p), then this implementation does not work properly. After I define it successfully on monomials, I will extend to all polynomials by linearity.

Comment: Your could use `arg1_ /; FreeQ[arg1, Plus]` to ensure monomialism.

Comment: Thank you @wxffles! -- this is much neater than the monster I was about to suggest: `myfcnX[arg1_, 
  arg2_] /; (And @@ (Length[MonomialList[#]] == 1 & /@ {arg1, arg2})) := ...` :)

Comment: This code gives the same results for `myfcn3[2 x, p]` and `myfcn3[x,p]`. This gives problems when I try to extend it to arbitrary polynomials.

Comment: @user2397833, yes it does. I presume you need `myfcn3[2 x, p]` to return unevaluated?

Comment: yes, that is correct.