# Problem with replacing a head with another head using pattern

Tags: pattern-matching

Why would this work

```
Times[a, b, c, d] /. Times :> List
(* {a, b, c, d} *)
```

but this doesn't work (the `Times` still remains even when the `List` has been added)?

```
Times[a, b, c, d] /. Times[p__] :> List[p]
(* {a b c d} *)
```

Applying `Trace` shows that `Times` might have applied itself to `p__` before the pattern is matched, so that the expression now became just `a b c d/. p__:>{p}`. If that's the case, why would `Times[p__]` become `p__`?

```
Times[a, b, c, d] /. Times[p__] :> List[p] // Trace
(* {{{Times[p__],p__},p__:>{p},p__:>{p}},a b c d/. p__:>{p},{a b c d}} *)
```

Comment: `Times[p__]` directly evaluates to `p__`.  You need `HoldPattern`, `Verbatim`, or a dummy pattern: `(x:Times)[p__]`.  This question is a duplicate.  I am looking now.

Comment: Please also see:  [(23066)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23066), [(25476)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25476), [(30152)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30152)

Comment: For clarity, all of these work: `Times[a, b, c, d] /. HoldPattern[Times[p__]] :> List[p]` -- 
`Times[a, b, c, d] /. HoldPattern[Times][p__] :> List[p]` -- `Times[a, b, c, d] /. Verbatim[Times][p__] :> List[p]` -- `Times[a, b, c, d] /. (x : Times)[p__] :> List[p]`

Comment: Bravo @Mr.Wizard! I learned something new today (`HoldPattern`) from you.

Comment: Glad I could help. :-)  By the way, while it doesn't answer this question you could also use:  `Times[a, b, c, d] /. p_Times :> List @@ p`.  However, be aware that this relies on evaluation of the righ-hand-side, meaning that it won't work inside a `Hold`:  `Hold[Times[a, b, c, d]] /. p_Times :> List @@ p` outputs `Hold[List @@ (a b c d)]`